# Offering a bounty after accepting an answer

Tags: discussion, bounty

Suppose a user posts a question, gets an answer and then accepts that answer.  Later on a new answer from another user is posted and the user posing the question wishes to accept both answers.  Since it is impossible to accept the second answer while still keeping the first answer accepted, is it considered to be acceptable to keep the first answer accepted and start a bounty on the question and then award it to the second answer?

Comment: If this is about the unsolvable Hashi/Bridges puzzle - Thanks, but my answer received such a ridiculous number of upvotes after the question became a Hot Network Question, that there is really no need to add a bounty on top of that.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  Ok.  That makes sense.

Comment: Sure, I've done it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that is a perfectly acceptable use of the bounty system. It's not something you'd ever be expected to do, and it's also completely fine to just upvote and move along, but if you feel an answer deserves a little extra credit then a bounty is one way to do it.